# Qt: event loop during closing

Tags: c++, qt

According this article [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects), is it Ok to say that, when we close a Qt programm. Once the mainWindow's close event started, nothing else except the close event handler and class deconstructor in the GUI thread will be executed?

For example, if there is a `QTimer` fired the `timeout()` signal in the GUI thread to a `slot` in the same thread. When the mainWindow's close event started, the slot will not get any chance to be executed again?

Comment: It depends... What you want to achieve? If you need to manage custom timers - you may set a flag `QApplicatoin::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed( false );` and manage an event loop by yourself.

Comment: I just worry that during the deconstruction, certain object might already be deleted manually (by calling `delete objectP`), if it so, when the `slot` is triggered by a timer and used the `objectP`, program will crash on exit.

Comment: Set a parent of your timer to your object - and everything will be ok ;)

Comment: Please, clarify your question being specific for your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's handled automatically:

> [QObject::~QObject()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)
>
> All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected, and
>   any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event
>   queue. However, it is often safer to use deleteLater() rather than
>   deleting a QObject subclass directly.

However for multi-threaded apps you need to use `deleteLater()` to avoid crashes:

> Warning: Deleting a QObject while pending events are waiting to be
>   delivered can cause a crash. You must not delete the QObject directly
>   if it exists in a different thread than the one currently executing.
>   Use deleteLater() instead, which will cause the event loop to delete
>   the object after all pending events have been delivered to it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is wrong on its face to say that once the mainWindow's close event started, nothing else will execute in the GUI thread except the close event handler and class destructors.

Suppose we have following code (in C++11):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QLabel label1("Hello, World!");
   label1.show();
   label1.setMinimumSize(200, 100);
   app.exec();

   QTimer timer;
   int counter = 0;
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&counter]{ counter ++; });
   timer.start(100);
   QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Done",
                            QString("We're Done with \"%1\"").arg(label1.text()));
   QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Really Done",
                            QString("Timer has ticked %1 times").arg(counter));
   return 0;
}
```

Obviously, non-destructor code *will* execute after `exec()` has returned - here we show a message box. The main window, in this case a `QLabel`, still exists after `exec()` has returned.

It is also incorrect to assume that somehow the timers will be globally killed after `exec()` has returned. They're still running, and as long as you re-start the event loop, they'll gladly fire for you. The second message box will display a non-zero count, after all.

Your question should be reworded with the problem you're trying to solve. You're asking for very specific details that make little sense on their own. Please tell use why you ask such a question.